# Can someone please explain why I am getting an error message that I am missing a return when I change one line of code

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

This line does not give me any errors:

```
if pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil {
    return (accumulator!.digit, true, pendingBinaryOperation!.description(pendingBinaryOperation!.descriptionOperand, accumulator?.literalDescription ?? " "), accumulator?.errorMessage)
} else  {
    return (accumulator!.digit, false, calculationDescription ?? "", accumulator?.errorMessage)
}
```

But this line does give me an error:

```
if pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil {
    return (accumulator!.digit, true, pendingBinaryOperation!.description(pendingBinaryOperation!.descriptionOperand, accumulator?.literalDescription ?? " "), accumulator?.errorMessage)
} else if accumulator!.digit != nil {
    return (accumulator!.digit, false, calculationDescription ?? "", accumulator?.errorMessage)
}
```

The message is:
Missing return in a function expected to return '(result: Double?, isPending: Bool, description: String, errorMessage: String?)' (aka '(result: Optional, isPending: Bool, description: String, errorMessage: Optional)')

Comment: Which branch is executed if you enter the if statement when `pendingBinaryOperation` and `accumulator!.digit` both are nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as in second code you wrap both returns inside an "IF" it assumes there might be a situation that none of them are true, and therefore you will not have any return at all.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason that comes up to my mind to get this error message is because of your program flow.

In first case it is always returning something based on the value of this `pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil` .

However in second case with such program flow where `pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil` is  **False** and also `accumulator!.digit != nil` is **False** , your code cannot hit something to return so it gives such an **error message** .

Answer (score 0):

You have a few unresolved conditions in the second piece of code.

```
if pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil {
    return (accumulator!.digit, true, pendingBinaryOperation!.description(pendingBinaryOperation!.descriptionOperand, accumulator?.literalDescription ?? " "), accumulator?.errorMessage)
} else if accumulator!.digit != nil {
    return (accumulator!.digit, false, calculationDescription ?? "", accumulator?.errorMessage)
}
```

That's your code. Let's look at the possible scenarios for `accumulator` first, and `pendingBinaryOperation` second:

- `accumulator != nil`, `pendingBinaryOperator != nil`. First clause is executed.
- `accumulator != nil`, `pendingBinaryOperator == nil`. Second clause is executed.
- `accumulator == nil`, `pendingBinaryOperator != nil || pendingBinaryOperator !== nil`. No return supplied.

That's two scenarios with no return.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the second expression is not exhaustive.

If both first and second conditions are evaluated to `false` there is no return value. That's what the error message states.

You need an extra `else` branch

```
if .... {
    return ...
} else if ... {
    return ...
} else {
    return ...
}
```

or a `return` statement at the end

```
if .... {
    return ...
} else if ... {
    return ...
} 
return ...
```